# Can't install python extension on visual studio: XHR failed,XHR failed,

Tags: python, visual-studio, proxy, dns

this is the error code where the plugin can't be installed

```
2023-01-12 11:26:54.575 [error] XHR failed,XHR failed,XHR failed: Error: XHR failed,XHR failed,XHR failed
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/names/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:87:88554
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at u (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/names/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:87:88540)
    at Z.D (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/names/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:87:79894)
    at async Z.z (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/names/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:87:77428)
    at async Z.installFromGallery (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/names/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:87:73871)
```

I have clear the DNS cache and this is my DNS setting:

```
 DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 229927932
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2A-7B-D7-CA-B4-6B-FC-45-73-47
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm already solve this problem by installing python extension from visual studio code marketplace manually and disconnect my device connection to internet